# Convert Time into 24 hour Format if charachters go beyond 24 hour in R

Tags: r, time, format

I do have a Variable in my Dataset which covers time in a 24 hour format. As the variable covers the time over multiple days the DF contains values which go beyond 24 hour e.g. "26:05:30").

How can I substract 24 hours from those values which did go beyond that?

The variable is in a character format.

I already tried using as.POSIXct but got the error that the string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into it's numbers; then use the modulo operator on the hours; then past the new values back together:

```
x = strsplit("26:05:30", ":")[[1]]
x[1] = as.integer(x[1]) %% 24
paste(x, collapse = ':')
# [1] "2:05:30"
```

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** `gsubfn` is like `gsub` except the replacement string can be a replacement function that inputs the match and outputs the replacement.  It can optionally be expressed in formula notation where the right hand side of the formula is the function body.  This gives the following one-liner.  If you don't want the hour to be zero filled then replace `sprintf(...)` with just `as.numeric(x) %% 24` :

```
library(gsubfn)

s <- c("26:05:30", "10:00:10")

gsubfn("^\\d+", ~ sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(x) %% 24), s)
## [1] "02:05:30" "10:00:10"
```

**(2)** This alternative uses only base R.  `s` is from above.  If you don't want the hour to be zero filled replace the first `%02d` with `%d`.

```
s |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = ":") |>
  with(sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", V1 %% 24, V2, V3))
## [1] "02:05:30" "10:00:10"
```